# Add title to a div in code behind is not appeared

Tags: html, asp.net

I'm using [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) popup from JQuery UI. I want to add a title to the popup and I found that only the `title` of the `div` should be filled.

When I write a constant value in the markup then the title is appeared, but when it's added in the code behind it is not appeared.

```
myDiv.Attributes["title"] = "some value";
```

-

```
<div id="myDiv" class="UsersDialogClass" 
                       runat="server" style="display: none">
```

Any idea!

Comment: @eugeneK: OK, it has been added.

Comment: do you knwo what div title attribute do?

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar, in jQuery UI it used to show Dialog box title

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
myDiv.Attributes.Add("title", "some value");
```

with the fact it is on Page_Load event.

Comment: but I'm add the value in an event, not in the `Page_Load`. why it effects?

Comment: then your problem is not CS code which adds title to a div... post your html of dialog and jQuery call.

Comment: @ eugeneK: Thanks, I knew that my problem is in setting the `title` in `Page_Load` but I can't because it will take its value from a control. How can I implement that please ?

Comment: @Jose, i don't know what you mean. With my code you assign title value to #myDiv, it should be on Page_Load because otherwise your jQuery Dialog code won't see title value on call.

Answer (score 2):

I have created a sample here,
you can override your title attribute when you load the dialog.

http://jsfiddle.net/jansian/HAq7w/1/

Comment: This link is no longer active.

Comment: I believe it is still active

Answer (score 0):

You may use asp:Panel server control and set it ToolTip property - it will render in div with appropriate title attribute value.